# Populate VBA Collection with Custom Objects using Collection.Add

Tags: vba, collections, object, for-loop

I am trying to add a custom object (Transaction) through the `sampleCollection.Add` from within a For loop.

The code works if I add strings to the collection instead of objects.

```
Public Function PopCollection()
    Dim sampleCollection As New Collection
    Dim objTrans As New Transaction
    Dim objTrans2 As New Transaction


    '********** SETUP ARRAY FOR LOOP *************
    Dim arrA(0 To 1) As String
    arrA(0) = "Description 1"
    arrA(1) = "Description 2"


    '********** POPULATE COLLECTION *************
    For n = 0 To 1
        objTrans.DESC = arrA(n)
        Call sampleCollection.Add(objTrans)
    Next n


    '********** ITERATE THROUGH COLLECTION *************
    For n = 1 To sampleCollection.Count
        Set objTrans2 = sampleCollection.Item(n)
        Debug.Print n & " - " & objTrans2.DESC
    Next n

End Function
```

The `Debug.Print n & " - " & objTrans2.DESC` line at the bottom of this code is outputting "Description 2" twice.  I want it to output "Description 1" and "Description 2".

Here is the information in the Transaction class:

```vb
Public PTXN As Integer
Public ACCTID As Integer
Public CHECKNUM As String
Public DESC As String
Public STATUS As String
Public TRANSACTIONDATE As String
Public SPLIT_DESC As String
Public SPLIT_AMT As Single
Public SPLIT_CATEGORY As Integer
```

I only added the property declarations to the VB editor in Excel. I copy/pasted what was listed there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to make a new instance of objTrans.  What you're doing is setting DESC to Description 1, adding to the collection, then changing DESC to Description 2 (not making a new objTrans instance), and adding that same instance to the collection a second time.  Here's how I would do it.

```
Public Function PopCollection()

    Dim sampleCollection As Collection
    Dim objTrans As Transaction
    Dim arrA As Variant
    Dim n As Long

    arrA = Array("Description 1", "Description 2")
    Set sampleCollection = New Collection

    For n = LBound(arrA) To UBound(arrA)
        Set objTrans = New Transaction
        objTrans.DESC = arrA(n)
        sampleCollection.Add objTrans
    Next n

    For n = 1 To sampleCollection.Count
        Set objTrans = sampleCollection.Item(n)
        Debug.Print n & " - " & objTrans.DESC
    Next n

End Function
```

Comment: Dick, that worked!!!  Thanks!  I spent hours trying to figure that out.  Thanks for the explanation and for the cleaned up code...I like seeing how other people would update my code.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly modified form (without the Transaction class) works as intended for me.  I believe there is an error is your Transaction class. Can you post the code for it?

Comment: Mitch, I added some more code to my description above.  

Maybe you can tell me what you used in place of my Transaction class?  Maybe I can try to get your code to work on my end.

Answer (score 0):

The simpler version would've been to set you n=0 to SampleCollection.Count as the indexes of an array starts with 0 and your n is starting with 1...

```
For n = 0 To sampleCollection.Count
    Set objTrans = sampleCollection.Item(n)
    Debug.Print n & " - " & objTrans.DESC
Next n
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can't populate VBA Collection with Custom Objects using Collection.add
>
> code is outputting "Description 2" twice

In basic simple terms, it is always better to do:

```
    Dim FooCollection As Collection
    Set FooCollection = New Collection
    
    Dim FooClass As classFoo
    Set FooClass = New classFoo
    FooCollection.Add FooClass
```

And not:

```
    Dim FooCollection As New Collection
    etc
```

As the latter will cause very subtle & not so apparent issues, & may not generate any errors, as I recently discovered.